# Kafka and firewall rules

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a fairly strict network segmentation policy. I am using a cloud foundry instance to deploy an app to. The firewall rules have been set up to reach the kafka cluster from within the cloud foundry instance. I believe that the firewall rules have also been set up to get to the zookeeper instance as well. I need to actually confirm that one.

My problem seems to be that I can produce messages to kafka, but my consumer doesn't seem to be picking them up. It seems to hang while "polling".

Is there some hidden hosts or ports that I need to deal with for my firewall rules that are not just the standard hosts and ports to the kafka and zookeeper nodes?

Comment: What are the list of ports that you have opened to communicate in the Kafka and zookeeper instance in the AWS Rule?

Comment: We are not using AWS, but they supposedly implemented access from cloud foundry to ports 9091, 9092, 2181. The first two are kafka. The last is zookeeper.

Comment: Are you running kafka under cluster setup or standalone? If cluster, then open the ports `2888 & 3888`. Port usage are, **2181** for client connections; **2888** for follower connections, if they are the leader; and **3888** for other server connections during the leader election phase. For more information use this [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_HDP_Reference_Guide/content/zookeeper-ports.html)

Comment: If I am using Kafka 0.10 consumer client, I don't need to tell the consumer anything about zookeeper. Is it still trying to talk to zookeeper. needing those ports open?

Comment: What I am trying to say is, if the zookeeper runs in cluster mode then, the port 2181 is used for client connections (kafka). the port 2888 is used for follower connections (peer zookeeper to follow leader), the port 3888 is used for leader election phase (peer zookeeper to elect the leader).

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I'm just not sure that it is relevant. It is my consuming application that is having trouble, not the kafka or zookeeper cluster itself. I have the same app running locally on my laptop with I suspect different firewalls rules, and it runs perfectly. It is when the app is running in my cloud foundry instance that it is not working. The question is whether the "app consumer" needs more firewall access than just the kafka cluster nodes on 9092, or 9091, which is supposedly what the firewall rules are set up for.

Answer (score 45):

Kafka and zookeeper are different things. If you are running both on the same machine, you need to open both ports, of corse.

kafka default ports:

- 9092, can be changed on server.properties;

zookeeper default ports:

- 2181 for client connections;
- 2888 for follower(other zookeeper nodes) connections;
- 3888 for inter nodes connections;

That's it.

Kafka, also has the ***listeners*** and ***advertised.listeners*** properties which grows some confusion on first users. To make it simple, *listener* is the network interface your server will bind, and *advertised.listeners* is the hostname or IP your server will register itself on zookeeper and listen to requests. If you put a hostname in there, your clients WILL have to use the hostname to connect. The *advertised.listeners* url is the one your clients will use to bootstrap the connection. Once connection is made, your client will get a connection to zookeeper to get other brokers urls. Your producer is not working because of that.

So, to make it work you need to open 2888 on your firewall too, not just 2181. And @Jaya Ananthram is wrong when he tells you that kafka needs 2181 port. It's a zookeeper port. The consumers on kafka 0.10 stills needs to contact zookeeper to persist some things, thats it.

Kafka 0.11.0.0 changed this and is making clients don't need zookeeper at all.

Comment: but what about random ports, when I start Kafka node on another machine(10.10.132.138)  I see the following log in zookeeper logs:
[2018-07-27 20:21:27,874] INFO Accepted socket connection from /10.10.132.138:53570 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2018-07-27 20:21:27,878] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /10.10.132.138:53570 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer).
So where does 53570 port come from?

Comment: wanted to add a link to my post https://boristyukin.com/connecting-to-kafka-on-virtualbox-from-windows/ to compliment an answer

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack 53570  is an ephemeral port from the client-side, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port

Comment: This works but there may be additional ports, such as 9091 . Check your `server.properties`.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** : There's no hidden port. Check your broker configuration. Make sure that it advertises IP/PORT that's reachable by Kafka consumers.

---

I came across this question after experiencing the same problem with Kafka 0.10.1.1 with kafka-python library as a consumer.

No. I captured network traffic and it doesn't use any other port to communicate with Kafka. If the brokers are configured to use 9092, it will be the only port used by consumers.

But upon further investigations, broker configurations were at fault in my case.

> kafka.advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://[private_ip]:9092,SSL://[public_ip]:9093
>   kafka.listeners = PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093

I used **[public_ip]:9092** as a bootstrap server because I did not have PKI set up but I wanted to test my consumer from public internet.

The consumer was able to connect to the broker but wasn't able to pull any message.

Since the consumer connected to Kafka using PLAINTEXT, Kafka advertised PLAINTEXT broker addresses instead of SSL addresses. The consumer then tried to reach Kafka brokers using private IP addresses instead of public ones. (as revealed by raw network capture)

After the PKI was enabled and configured in brokers & clients, I was able to pull messages from public internet just fine.

Comment: This answer is misleading. While correct for standalone Kafka instances, it doesn't take into account that when running in a cluster Kafka also needs ports 2888 and 3888 for follower connections and leader election. The question is about a Kafka cluster, not a standalone instance.